# I'm writing this simple code on latex

Tags: latex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\end{document}
```

This code returns an error of

> Missing $ inserted. $\end{matrix}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `matrix` environment needs to be in math mode. Either of these will work:

```
% in-line math mode
\(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\)
```

or

```
% display math mode
\[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\]
```

There is a [TeX/LaTeX StackExchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) that is more appropriate for this sort of question.

Answer (score -1):

This method is far superior:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c c|}

        1 & 0\\
        0 & 1
    \end{tabular}\\

\vspace{1cm}

    $\left[
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            1 & 0\\
            0 & 1
    \end{tabular}
    \right]$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why: "This method is far superior"? Is it faster? is it less draining on system resources? Is it a new function? Or perhaps another reason?

Comment: This will use text font for the matrix which will be inconsistent with the surrounding math environment and will also prevent the usage of any special math characters.